# Intellij include src files in jar file

Tags: java, build, jar, intellij-idea

I remember a while back with eclipse or netbeans I was able to easily include my source files in my jar file. I have moved to intellij 10 community edition and find myself needing to do the same thing. Any hints?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I figured it out...

Click the '+' button in the 'output layout' tab -> include directory contents -> select your src directory. That did it

Answer (score 3):

did you try this

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/tag/artifacts/

basically you

1. right click on the project
2. select Open Module Settings
3. add a build artefact of type jar.  You should see something like
   [image]
4. Now in the build menu option you can build the jar.

Comment: That would set up a standard jar build, which only includes dependencies and class files, not source files. (Sorry, my question may have been unclear)

Answer (score 3):

Navigate as follows :

(i) Go the "File" in the Top Menu Bar

(ii) Select "Project Structure" from the File Menu

(iii) Select "Artifacts" in Project Settings

(iv) Select "Output Layout"

(v) Click on "+" , select "Directory Content" from the dropdown and choose "src" folder from the directories.