# play 2.0: how to generate the IntelliJ IDEA project with dependecy docs and sources included?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, playframework-2.0

I know the `idea` command will generate the *.iml file (Idea module file)

But the generated file does not include dependency docs and sources.

Will `gen-idea` of [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) help?

Comment: Maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751417/intellij-include-src-files-in-jar-file) will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `gen-idea` works for me!

Great! [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) rock!

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `sbt` logs.
Most probably the src is missing in the reposetory.
I get this while trying to fetch src for eclipse.

```
project files for your project(s). [warn] [NOT FOUND ]
org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.1!scala-library.jar(src) (0ms)
```

Comment: No No. I use ```sbt update-classifiers```, and downloaded nearly all docs and sources.