# How to attach source code for debugging in jar intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I wanted to add source code to my custom jar.

I tried adding "src" folder to jar by selecting

> ** File->Project Structure->Artifect->output layout->"+"**

. But It did not work for me.

I even tried adding "src" folder by clicking **"CTRL+click"->Attach** source. It says attaching but nothing happens.

Is there any way to add source code while creation of jar?

I am using Intelij-Idea 14.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in Android studio 1.2 because of that source attachment was not working. It is fixed in 1.3. For go to this link https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=181416

To fix this update your Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jdc0589s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113173/jdc0589) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751417/intellij-include-src-files-in-jar-file).

> Click the '+' button in the 'output layout' tab -> include directory contents -> select your src directory.

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: No, this does not help. It says attaching but nothing happens,